# PHP 5.3.2: Deprecated method of instantiating an object?

Tags: php, deprecated

Getting a white screen of death, so decided to remote debug an application that I suspect is instantiating an object using a now unsupported method:

`$type['content_object'] = new $type['handler_class']();`

Is this still legitimate?

Comment: Turns error reporting on... The class name may be incorect.

Comment: You aren't invoking a method with the above code - just instantiating a class. Your answer may depend on the contents of `$type['handler_class']`.

Comment: Display_errors = on error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT and just getting white screen. Restarted apache.

Comment: @doug: meant "way" not method as in the OO sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$type['handler_class']` is a string containing the name of a class, then it's fine, according to [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> If a string containing the name of a class is used with new, a new instance of that class will be created.
>
> ```
> <?php
>     $instance = new SimpleClass();
>
>     // This can also be done with a variable:
>     $className = 'Foo';
>     $instance = new $className(); // Foo()
> ?>
> ```

Comment: That assumes that `$type['handler_class']` is a string containing the name of a class.