# Why didn't a missing class file throw a PHP error?

Tags: php, error-handling

Sorted out [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326437/php-5-3-2-deprecated-method-of-instantiating-an-object).  Problem was the class file (and the folder, actually) was missing.  Puzzled why with `display_errors = On` and `E_ALL | E_STRICT` defined (and Apache restarted), this would throw a white screen of death and not an error.

phpinfo() shows that the master value and the local value are the same, so I'm assuming that the error settings are not being overwritten somewhere in the code base (in an .htaccess or `ini_set()` call).

EDIT

The new object instantiation is here:

`$type['content_object'] = new $type['handler_class']();`

I also tried instantiating it without the variable, i.e. `new Foo();` but still gave WSOD.

Comment: Is the line of code that threw the error inside a file that is included with an include/require statement that has error reporting suppressed with the @ operator?  (i.e. inside a file called like `@require('file.php')`.I've done that a few times before.

Comment: @Pete: it's been instantiated within a method of another class; there's two `require_once` lines at the top, but no `@`.

Comment: print the output of `error_reporting()` right before the line with the error. That should tell you if the error reporting was disabled (0 means disabled, like `@` does). You can do the same with `ini_get('display_errors')`.

Comment: @Rijk: returns `1` so it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an alternative error handler activated. Call `restore_error_handler()` prior to the line with the error (possibly multiple times) to reactivate PHP's default error handler.